docker stats stopped working
This morning docker stats was working fine. But now I get:
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
84d1fc988d3f   root-adminer-1         0.00%     0B / 0B             0.00%     99.6kB / 0B       0B / 0B     0
777c51376bfb   root-nginx-1           0.00%     0B / 0B             0.00%     252kB / 198kB     0B / 0B     0
7cb21454bab9   root-certbot-1         0.00%     0B / 0B             0.00%     135kB / 0B        0B / 0B     0
449df6b34a9d   root-bookstack-1       0.00%     0B / 0B             0.00%     155kB / 4.71kB    0B / 0B     0
4438fc531cd8   root-watchtower-1      0.00%     0B / 0B             0.00%     136kB / 0B        0B / 0B     0
7bcb683c69aa   root-mariadb-1         0.00%     0B / 0B             0.00%     387kB / 1.46MB    0B / 0B     0

When I look at docker info I get:
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpu shares support
WARNING: No cpuset support
WARNING: No io.weight support
WARNING: No io.weight (per device) support
WARNING: No io.max (rbps) support
WARNING: No io.max (wbps) support
WARNING: No io.max (riops) support
WARNING: No io.max (wiops) support

Today, I played with the firewall and I adjusted my docker-compose.yml. But I can't think of anything that should have broken docker stats. I've tried rebooting. I've tried reverting what I did with the docker-compose.yml. Whatever I was trying to achieve with the firewall got me nowhere and I think I reverted it all.
Anyone know how to fix this?
 Server Version: 25.0.3
 Kernel Version: 6.1.25
 Operating System: OpenWrt 23.05.3
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64

It really did work this morning.
